# Marking overlay icon as "selected" without changing icon

Tags: android, itemizedoverlay, mapactivity

I have an android mapActivity which displays icons on the map using ItemizedOverlays.

If a user taps on an Icon, I want the user to see the icon as "selected" (making it transparent for example, or something of that sort). Is there a way to do it without using setMarker() for another icon?

Answer (score 0):

use `setState`

Try this link for more information on this.[Developers.Google: Maps Documentation - Android Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/)